# How to replace behavior renderer?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm using RichFaces 4 and I need to replace renderer for behavior `org.richfaces.component.behavior.ClientValidatorImpl`. I can do this by overriding the behavior itself and specifying type of my renderer:

```
@FacesBehavior("org.richfaces.behavior.MyClientValidator")
public class MyClientValidatorImpl extends ClientValidatorImpl {
    @Override
    public String getRendererType() {
        return MyClientValidatorRenderer.RENDERER_TYPE;
    }
}
```

but how to avoid that unnecessary overriding?

Comment: What makes you think it is unnecessary? Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: @TimB Because this class actually doesn't carry any payload. It would be nice to provide custom renderer in `faces-config.xml` as it is done for components.

Comment: "Unnecessary"? You either override or roll your own. Why do you want to replace it?

Comment: @kolossus I just want to provide custom `ComponentValidatorScript` in my renderer and looking for a simpler way to do that. Of course the solution with overridden class of the behavior works perfectly but looks a bit cumbersome for me.